# Trying to compute a correlation between two variables where one variable has NaN values

Tags: correlation, survival, missing-data, censoring

I'm trying to see if there's a relationship between age of onset of substance use and another variable. However, I have participants that have never tried any substances (~10%) of my dataset for whom the value would therefore be a nan?
How would you go about examining this relationship?
I thought about looking into years since first use, in which case becomes zero for those people, but the data was collected at different points so I don't want to do that, I only want to look into early onset's relationship with my variable.

Comment: (a) Maybe consider never-users as a separate group, and see how they compare with those who started using drugs at some age. (b) Maybe take the cynical view that everyone will start _sometime_ and  assign current age + 20 or something like 99 to NaN's. Hard to say without knowing what the 'other factor' is and whether you're pondering some kind of causal relationship.

Comment: I ended up creating a scale based on age of onset and assigned a number to never as well. Saw another paper that did that. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This situation would readily be handled by survival analysis. Age at onset or at last follow-up would be the outcome variable, further coded as to whether the time represented an event (onset at that time) or not (censored time, no onset as of last follow-up). The other variable(s) would be included as predictor(s) in the model. Choice between a continuous-time or a discrete-time analysis would depend on the nature of the data. A [cure model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/119801/28500) might be appropriate if some are thought never to have an onset of substance use, but with no more than 10% in that category I doubt that such a more complicated model would be any better.